# Centering a contact form button using CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css

I tried posting my code but the system would not allow me to this this without an indent.

My button aligns left on my website yet it is centered properly when I preview it in CSS

http://reverseloansforseniors.com/ppcfbk/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! 1. Every code editor has options to handle indentation. For HTML/CSS/JS, there's also a **code snippet tool** to easily insert code. 2. Please do not link to your homepage, otherwise your question may be considered spam.

Answer (score 1):

Your `p` element have `text-align: justify !important` CSS. For setting this button on center you Just change your `HTML` code like below

```
<p style="text-align: center !important;">
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" margin="auto">
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. My difficulty is removing div classes with something else. The div created changes to the entire page color. I only want the form color changed. Replacing the div will eliminate this.                                                                         <div>
        <input id="fname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" />
            <input id="lphone" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone" type="text" />
            <input id="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" type="text" />
            <input id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="Message" type="text" />

Answer (score 0):

Try centering the element with css using the following

`<p style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">`